# Determine the function to which the Fourier series converges for $f(x)=x$

Tags: fourier-series

Determine the function to which the Fourier series converges for $f(x)$ given the following

$$f(x)=x,~~~~~-\pi<x<\pi$$

Solution: \begin{align*}
a_0&=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} x dx\\
&=\frac{1}{\pi}\left[\frac{x^2}{2}\right]_{-\pi}^{\pi}\\
&=0.
\end{align*}
Since $f(x)$ is odd  so $a_n=0$.

\begin{align*} 
b_n&=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)\sin(nx)dx\\
&=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi x\sin(nx)dx\\
&=\frac{1}{\pi}\left[\frac{x\cos (nx)}{n}+\dfrac{\sin(nx)}{n^{2}}\right]_{-\pi}^{\pi}\\
&=-\frac{1}{n\pi}[\pi\cos(nx)-(-\pi)\cos(-n\pi)]\\
 &= -\frac{1}{n\pi}\cdot 2\pi\cos(n\pi)\\
 & = \frac{2\cdot(-1)^{n+1}}{n}
\end{align*}

Therefore, the required fourier series is $$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2\cdot(-1)^{n+1}}{n} \sin nx.$$

Help with the second part!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: At $\pm \pi$ the series has all terms $0$ and so the sum is $0$. At other points it converges to $x$ by basic results on convergence of Fourier series.

Comment: Yeah right! can you please solve it for me, I am a bit confused

Comment: To be precise the series converges to the periodic extension of $x$ outside $(-\pi,\pi)$ and is zero at all integer multiples of $\pi$. The graph looks like a sawtooth.

Comment: $$
\sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{2( - 1)^{n + 1} }}{n}\sin (nx)}  = 2\operatorname{Im} \sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{( - 1)^{n + 1} }}{n}e^{ixn} }  = 2\operatorname{Im} \log (1 + e^{ix} ) = x + 2\pi \left\lfloor \frac{\pi-x}{2\pi} \right\rfloor 
$$

Comment: Shouldn't one be more careful with the series $\sum_{n \ge 1}\frac{(-1)^{n + 1}z}{n}$? Because radius of convergence of this series is $1$ and there is a singularity at $z = -1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question follows from the following general theorem:

If the function $F$ is differentiable at the point $x_0$ then its Fourier series at the point $x_0$ converges to $F(x_0)$.

Comment: Probably you want to show the convergence by hands? For example, one way to show the convergence (not necessarily to $f(x)$) of the series is the Dirichet test for the monotone sequence $a_n = \frac{1}{n}$ and the sequence $b_n = (-1)^{n+1}\sin(nx)$ satisfying $\sup_N|\sum_{n = 1}^Nb_n| < \infty$.

Comment: Thanks Pavel! Please look the title, which convergent I need to find. Can I just show that Foueries series of $f(x)$ converges or converges to $f(x)$? Actually my English is weak.

Comment: It does converge to $f(x)$ on $[-\pi, \pi)$ and to the periodic continuation of $f$  everywhere else.

Comment: The function is piecewise smooth and, in the interval $(-\pi,\pi)$ its periodic extension is same as original function. Hence the Fourier series converges to $f(x)$ for all $x\in(-\pi,\pi)$. Is this OK?

Comment: Yes, it is absolutely correct